# Help needed improving a foreach loop

Tags: php

I have this logic written that loops out an array into `<li>`

and gives #1 and every 5th a class of "alpha".

```
$count = 0;

        foreach($gallery->data as $row){

            if ($count==0 || $count%4==0) {
                echo '<li class="alpha"></li>'.PHP_EOL;
            } else {
                echo '<li></li>'.PHP_EOL;
            }

            $count++;
        }
```

I need to add to this and get the code adding a class of "omega" to every 4th `<li>`

Comment: You don't need `if $count == 0`. The second part of the if statement will already add 'alpha' to the first element at index 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do realize that as you describe it, there will be some overlap right? (example - item 30 is both a '5th' and a '6th')  Brian gave you an answer for exactly what you described, but I'm not sure if its what you want.  You want ALPHA, x, x, x, OMEGA, ALPHA, x, x, x, OMEGA, ALPHA.....

You seem to want Alpha on the 5*k + 1, and Omega on 5*k

conditions:
alpha - ($count + 1) % 5 == 1
omega - ($count + 1) % 5 == 0

I think grouping in the addition makes this easier to understand, since you're count starts at 0 but you seem to be thinking in terms of beginning at 1.  If you don't like that, lose the addition and change the equivalences to 0 and 4, respectively - $count % 5 == 0 and $count % 5 == 4

i know this is better suited for a comment under the last answer, but I don't see how.  Am i not allowed until my reputation is higher or am i just missing something?>

Comment: Thanks for your input Jon, that seems to have done the trick!

Comment: no problem.  glad i could help, and im pumped just to have my first approved answer hah

Answer (score 0):

right now as it stands your code adds the "alpha" class to every **fourth** item beginning with the first, not every fifth. In other words, items 1, 5, 9, 13, etc. will have a class of "alpha" since your counter begins at 0.

I assume that you want to add the "omega" class then to items 4, 8, 12, etc. Here's what you need to do that:

```
$count = 0;

    foreach($gallery->data as $row){ 

        if ($count%4==0) { 
            echo '<li class="alpha"></li>'.PHP_EOL; 
        }
        else if ($count%4==3) {
            echo '<li class="omega"></li>'.PHP_EOL;
        } 
        else { 
            echo '<li></li>'.PHP_EOL; 
        } 

        $count++; 
    }
```

Comment: That's exactly is. Sorry, I think I was getting mixed up myself!

Comment: So I can better understand how this works, can you explain what I would change to adjust the order. For example: alpha on #1 and every 6th, and omega on every 5th?

Comment: The % operator gives you the remainder of a divided by b when you have the expression a%b. In your case you're using the value obtained from $count%4 as an offset within a grouping, where the first item appears when $count%4 = 0 and the last item appears where $count%4 = 3. If you wanted to change the size of your group while still retaining the first/last relationship for an arbitrary group size N, the first item occurs where $count%N = 0 and the last item occurs where $count%N = N-1.

Comment: Spoke too soon I think, I'm getting unpredictable results. I don't think its a PHP issue, more like my bad math. Brain, any chance you could tell me what the values should be for that example above (alpha on #1 and every 6th, and omega on every 5th).

Comment: sure. You'd change $count%4 to $count%6 and ($count%4==3) to ($count%6==5)

Comment: how is that strange? you have alpha on 1, 7, 13, 19, etc. and omega on 6, 12, 18, etc. (every 6th and 5th, respectively, beginning from 1). If that's not what you meant, ie: you wanted alpha on 1, 6, 11, 16, etc and omega on 5, 10, 15, etc then use $count%5 and ($count%5==4)