# PHP counter increment for every 1st and 4th div

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am running a wordpress if while statement and would like my items to display in a column format.

I am currently using `960.gs` which is your standard 960 grid system, and by default adds `10px padding` to left and right, by simply passing a class of `alpha` or `omega` you can get rid of these.

How do I get php to execute a statment for every 1st one to add alpha and 4th one omega?

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="grid_4">
        <?php $wp_query->is_home = false; ?>
        <div class="entry">
            <h3 style="margin-bottom:10px;"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
             <?php //the_excerpt() ?>
         </div>
     </div>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try maybe something like this. I wasn't sure what you meant by every 1st and 4th so I made it the way you can see. You should be able to customize it yourself.

```
<?php $counter = 0; ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php
        $div = '<div class="entry';
        if ($counter % 4 == 0)
            $div .= " alpha";
        else if($counter % 4 == 3)
            $div .= " omega";
        echo $div . '">';
    ?>
    <div class="grid_4">
        <?php $wp_query->is_home = false; ?>
        <div class="entry">
            <h3 style="margin-bottom:10px;"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
             <?php //the_excerpt() ?>
         </div>
     </div>
     <?php $counter++; ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="grid_4">
        <?php $wp_query->is_home = false; ?>
        <div class="entry <?php if (!($i++ % 4)) { ?>alpha<?php } ?> <?php if (!(($j++)+1 % 4)) { ?>omega<?php } ?>">
            <h3 style="margin-bottom:10px;"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
            <?php //the_excerpt() ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks kind of like a repeat of something I've seen recently.  (Not your fault, it was poorly named and you wouldn't have been able to search on it).  [Help needed improving a foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935544/help-needed-improving-a-foreach-loop/3936227#3936227)

I think what you're looking for would be more precisely described as class=alpha on row 4k+1, class=omega on row=4k

I'm not familiar with your if/while syntax, and the embedded PHP throws me off a little.  But I think what you want to do:

is initialize a counter to 0 before the while loop ($i = 0).  Increment it at the end of the loop ($i++)

I'm not sure where you want to put these classes, but put if ($i%4==1) class="alpha" and if(i%4==0) class="omega" (add php tags as appropriate, for some reason they werent showing up right for me).